# Angular: date filter adds timezone, how to output UTC?

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I'm using the date filter to render a unix timestamp in a certain format. I've noticed the filter adds the local timezone to the output.

Is there any way to simply output the exact timestamp, without adding any timezone information?

Input:

```
talk.content.date_and_time = 1400167800
```

(is 05 / 15 / 14 @ 3:30:00pm UTC)

Code:

```
{{talk.content.date_and_time*1000 | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm Z'}}
```

Output:

```
15-5-2014 17:30 +0200
```

How can I make the output 15:30 instead of 17:30?

Comment: What's your code? What's the input, what's the output? What's the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. Added to the question @JBNizet.

Comment: if you pass a raw integer number of milliseconds, the Date filter will interpret it with respect to local time still.  However using the UTC constructor and passing a date or pre-empting the filter's timezone offset by adding the offset to your own millis and passing it seems to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The 'Z' is what adds the timezone info.  As for output UTC, that seems to be the subject of some confusion -- people seem to gravitate toward [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Borrowing from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc#answer-6777470), you could do something like this without moment.js:

**controller**

```
var app1 = angular.module('app1',[]);

app1.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){

  var toUTCDate = function(date){
    var _utc = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
    return _utc;
  };

  var millisToUTCDate = function(millis){
    return toUTCDate(new Date(millis));
  };

    $scope.toUTCDate = toUTCDate;
    $scope.millisToUTCDate = millisToUTCDate;

  }]);
```

**template**

```
<html ng-app="app1">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.12" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div>
      utc {{millisToUTCDate(1400167800) | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm'}}
      </div>
      <div>
      local {{1400167800 | date:'dd-M-yyyy H:mm'}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

here's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLwnLZReCy8HXtJyO84q?p=preview) to play with it

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470139/angularjs-timestamp-to-formatted-utc-time-with-date-helper).

Also note that with this method, if you use the 'Z' from Angular's date filter, it seems it will still print your local timezone offset.

Comment: rather than a function in the controller, you could, as others have proposed, incorporate `millisToUTCDate` into a filter.

Comment: You can also merge this two functions into one.
`var millisToUTCDate = function(millis){
    var date new Date(millis);
    return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(),  date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
  };`

This was helpful for me cos' I wasn't able to make filters work :/. Thanks.

Answer (score 97):

Since version `1.3.0` AngularJS introduced extra filter parameter `timezone`, like following:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

But in versions `1.3.x` only supported timezone is `UTC`, which can be used as following:

```
{{ someDate | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : 'UTC' }}
```

Since version `1.4.0-rc.0` AngularJS supports other timezones too. I was not testing all possible timezones, but here's for example how you can get date in Japan Standard Time (JSP, GMT +9):

```
{{ clock | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : '+0900' }}
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) you can find documentation of AngularJS date filters.

**NOTE:** this is working only with Angular 1.x

Here's [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yy4yPL2RMyFcCZlCasGa?p=preview)

Comment: Sadly this additional timezone parameter is not supported in [Angular 2's Date pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html).  Doing something like what is suggested in the first answer will still work in Angular 2.

Comment: @user3640967 this works only for Angular 1.x, but not for Angular 2

Comment: what to do for Angular2 (Local date to UTC), i search lot but could not reach to conclusion , so if you guide me then i will help full.

Comment: For Angular2 you have to create controller or utility function to convert date to UTC and back. You can check accepted answer for example on how to do it.

Comment: Also probably works for IANA timezones such as `'Europe/Berlin'`

Answer (score 0):

The date filter always formats the dates using the local timezone. You'll have to write your own filter, based on the `getUTCXxx()` methods of [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or on a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I just used getLocaleString() function for my application. It should adapt the timeformat common to the locale, so no +0200 etc. Ofcourse, there will be less possibility for controlling the width of your string then.

```
var str = (new Date(1400167800)).toLocaleString();
```