# Date filter. Unable to show date in UTC time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I'm using filter to format date string.

```
$filter('date')(
                "2016-01-19T23:07:37Z",
                'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

but this always returns `2016-01-20` (I'm in +1 timezone).

I tried to att optional parameter with Timezone.
Already tried:

- "UTC"
- "UTC/GMT"
- "GMT"

But always I get `2016-01-20` instead of `2016-01-19`

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: date filter adds timezone, how to output UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782893/angular-date-filter-adds-timezone-how-to-output-utc)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was using version 1.2.3 of angular without support for timezones. My fault.